# Why is this function behaving differently on calling first time and second time in React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to implement a turn by turn navigation with mapbox gl js in react,I am trying to make the marker positon update smooth instead of it being teleported.So to perform the animation I am trying to call a function recursively but for some reason the same function behaves differently when called second time compared to the first,code snippet is given below ([logs](https://ibb.co/m9X5thT))

```js
const animateMarker = () => {
  setSteps(0);
  const lng = endlongitude - longitude;
  const lat = endlatitude - latitude;
  setDeltaLng(lng / numDeltas);
  setDeltaLat(lat / numDeltas);

  makeAnimation();
};


const makeAnimation = () => {
  let t = 0;

  setLatitude(latitude + deltaLat);
  setLongitude(longitude + deltaLng);
  let lat = 13.0547712;
  let lng = 80.1144832;

  const loop = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      lng = lng + deltaLng;
      lat = lat + deltaLat;
      console.log(lat);
      t++;
      usermarker ? .setLngLat([lng + deltaLng, lat + deltaLat]);
      if (t != numDeltas) {
        loop();
      }
    }, 100);
  };
  loop();
};



<!-- end snippet -

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

> I am using normal JS variables instead of react useState because useState doesnt work in 
recursive state updation.This behaviour is very weird ,also I have attached the console log for the variable showing both functions running but behaving differently
```

```html
 <button
        className="nav-btn"
        onClick={(e) => {
          animateMarker();
        }}
      >
        navigate
      </button>
```

->

`

Comment: Please provide a demo of your code. What happened? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: site:[link](https://imaginative-twilight-6df2ba.netlify.app) ,expected behaviour is the marker should smoothly move towards the destination but it snaps back to the original position while animating.The first function call behaves differently with second call.To recreate please click on the map to create a destination and press navigate twice,because the first call doesnt work properly even though the function is called.Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still having trouble seeing the demo. Could you reproduce using a codepen/stackblitz/codesandbox, without location permissions?

Comment: site:[link](https://imaginative-twilight-6df2ba.netlify.app/),please check now,It should not ask location permissions.the values are static now,thank you.

Comment: Hey,I think i found the problem.the react state update is asynchronous,so on the first function call the delta value is not updated but in the second it is updated.sorry my bad,thanks for your time and effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `makeAnimation` captured the value of the state values when you first called it, so it won't update the `delta` variables.

Consider using the functional form of the `setState` hook.

Comment: I tried to use useState hook in a recursive function but the value is not getting updated,thats why I ended up using normal javascript variable,any idea why is that a case,also do you know how to use setState in recursive function calls,thank you.

Comment: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/